# Mosaico not sending as HTML mails

Tags: civimail, mosaico

EDIT

We're not sure if this is due to a PHP update at our ISP but the Civi Mosaico instance has stopped sending as HTML mails and writes the HTML as code into the mails.

All the WordPress plugins are up to date and all the Civi Extensions are up to date.

Thank you.

See email source:

```
Original Message
Message ID  <E1p8d8U-000BK7-F4@dedi305.cpt4.host-h.net>
Created at: Fri, Dec 23, 2022 at 10:10 AM (Delivered after 19 seconds)
From:   
To:  <>
Subject:    [CiviMail Draft] 10:09am
SPF:    SOFTFAIL with IP 196.40.103.35 Learn more
DKIM:   'FAIL' with domain  Learn more


Download Original   Copy to clipboard   
Delivered-To: 
Received: by 2002:a59:1a14:0:b0:37f:b9bf:8335 with SMTP id a20csp167914vqa;
        Fri, 23 Dec 2022 00:10:53 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AMrXdXswREmdQwvOp5x1+tBeQENFgpBuFAaIJe3TRaShsvl09VSVMSOcu0eKUY1OeAz6cmT8Hlx9
X-Received: by 2002:a17:906:1414:b0:78d:f455:b5dd with SMTP id p20-20020a170906141400b0078df455b5ddmr6479979ejc.29.1671783053463;
        Fri, 23 Dec 2022 00:10:53 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1671783053; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=iDkJFgK3KItqvcm/TJlsgV1NWILz61GsugHPxwVLrXBhH3Oj5aJng0PNJSDYLIiLBW
         IRsurJX6oQ84HEq8O0GuwukuIzUrP0SwpRuUgByJAL0eq+XRGVJLiAwqLlsI4Cw3ylTI
         I9VR2Q7ffFyZf39I04Tjz4cMBc1FNurOiEzDRf1Uu1mJgKosAJoU5jNby1ZEjkkunCem
         nWMh0qBtHNKVWUHF2HE/H5NlYU5ZZBfcpkZA7dusEKLMBgWtCXZyR1oSpwrpgm27uuZ/
         SfWqfMAAkni2prGA8yWHHuXz9fhj3aARTp2Tq4jqDQy+Gd/oCbeiYq9YZJc9viZc7WCI
         ohwA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=from:date:message-id:mime-version:subject:to:dkim-signature;
        bh=xyL/WgcSuvnUfHnEVdiH0rLeJVsHQ4C8DbdIPwMaNYo=;
        b=gxPGWJxx/sGtsSm7ABihI2x6Q1OHFyN7ScrrD8Vy3heNJ2wiqshNNgipRLzWUssyxO
         h4taH4gX8+lTHk9qPHCnc1eOgpAVUncks61GpGIq1clz9ZzMwr36xU1wDBInYTww5y1U
         QOrnKpe3r3Dg2BrHzmAMCUpiikUf/XVzfp7JzXkSSzVMlDzdYJ4HeflixzO67bIJayci
         lhQG5EkVl4M9EjeMMojrzZcZgPZMxqF5MLAI9mIrJkMtXo71j9ZGWxJhER123AoWmptd
         SC9oZb5ifj8ockE0OUsJTNwvTte+fxtZisbQGrLfi2sMyDLotFw7jRbQgJk5EqZVYEoq
         AKZQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@ header.s=xneelo header.b=CA9VssWq;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning  does not designate 196.40.103.35 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=
Return-Path: <>
Received: from outgoing44.cpt4.host-h.net (outgoing44.cpt4.host-h.net. [196.40.103.35])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ww2-20020a170907084200b007416e100f3dsi2068750ejb.986.2022.12.23.00.10.52
        for <>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Fri, 23 Dec 2022 00:10:53 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning  does not designate 196.40.103.35 as permitted sender) client-ip=196.40.103.35;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@ header.s=xneelo header.b=CA9VssWq;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning  does not designate 196.40.103.35 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=; s=xneelo; h=From:Date:Message-Id:MIME-Version:Subject :To:reply-to:sender:cc:bcc:in-reply-to:references:content-type: content-transfer-encoding; bh=xyL/WgcSuvnUfHnEVdiH0rLeJVsHQ4C8DbdIPwMaNYo=;
     b=CA9VssWq3cXUYy04g2PUA4gVSE6iY84TNdSK3MynAb0DEAO4sBdDP7i6Ad8Lm7CatRLldtAqUw L5qrt/YHcZBInS0dlsAMBGi0wtDCy+myZ3MNYBxkOwxiCMRl6sc0VpdJUlJF6BnUZ+MWOf1n48nFv nxksQI/GPK+iTE0pBW6WTTMacF7Y+UYdwqs/8e+qRJOVNrbZk/9u1lZNm2EQMhYKUcXUkhIUbvuy3 tDVJ49uQ9n95FtT+hPOyrDRmNTbsK77yZiXkw71utAG4tDGLUs4UyzSIbSpVkyjPdFwMDxwVgFGpu kqTOJkWSRo1TyCgPbPgDoQ99XtIt9vf0YImqQ==;
Received: from dedi305.cpt4.host-h.net ([197.221.0.197]) by antispam7-cpt4.host-h.net with esmtpsa (TLSv1.3:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256) (Exim 4.92) (envelope-from <>) id 1p8d8f-0005By-7r for ; Fri, 23 Dec 2022 10:10:51 +0200
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1] helo=dedi305.cpt4.host-h.net) by dedi305.cpt4.host-h.net with esmtps (TLS1.3:ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256) (Exim 4.92) (envelope-from <>) id 1p8d8U-000BKT-LF for ; Fri, 23 Dec 2022 10:10:34 +0200
Received: from highwjmbkf by dedi305.cpt4.host-h.net with local (Exim 4.92) (envelope-from <b.108.22813.8094da182867d219@>) id 1p8d8U-000BK7-F4 for ; Fri, 23 Dec 2022 10:10:34 +0200
To:  <>
Subject: [CiviMail Draft] 10:09am
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1594:mail.php
MIME-Version: 1.0 X-CiviMail-Mosaico: Yes List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:u.108.22813.8094da182867d219@> Precedence: bulk job_id: 108 From: "Highway Hospice" <fundraising@> Return-Path: b.108.22813.8094da182867d219@ X-CiviMail-Bounce: b.108.22813.8094da182867d219@ Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="=_0964fc6b5afd6aeec2ef8cae672582fa" Date: Fri, 23 Dec 2022 10:10:34 +0200
Message-Id: <E1p8d8U-000BK7-F4@dedi305.cpt4.host-h.net>
Date: Fri, 23 Dec 2022 10:10:34 +0200
X-Original-Sender: b.108.22813.8094da182867d219@
From: 
X-Original-Sender: b.108.22813.8094da182867d219@
X-Spoofed: [ b.108.22813.8094da182867d219@ ] may be spoofed
X-Hetz-Sender-Domain: 
X-Originating-IP: 197.221.0.197
X-SpamExperts-Domain: 
X-SpamExperts-Username: 
Authentication-Results: host-h.net; auth=pass (login) smtp.auth=@
X-SpamExperts-Outgoing-Class: ham
X-SpamExperts-Outgoing-Evidence: Combined (0.23)
X-Recommended-Action: accept
X-Filter-ID: Pt3MvcO5N4iKaDQ5O6lkdGlMVN6RH8bjRMzItlySaT8WtF6gmR1WY5QmYklOfJt4PUtbdvnXkggZ 3YnVId/Y5jcf0yeVQAvfjHznO7+bT5w9wnaFLRMkf1Y4W+ClMbQqvWPMmWE2UYfqyb5H+bsYmtcV PSoHm0W/3adFfiYl2nv8cqJA6bYm9N7bRNMCupfl/T4GcPvCLvSpAEEGy7kYxuMa88YE66E9fBno Af7rqCusOKjAUmV0C9KuYSjH4lBdhFHN71l54rACCRHfNouFNpuBoKRbycab+xivlMZxSt1QjgNL hnE6LCVa09fPSMLwzYS69kWBtyjohdIfAyfx0Iq36YELusVp6zmtkp3fm8ksOdAaBGAeOKhTx+m3 vF4LsArQv+5M23dYLDjUbMZvVmr6m72Gjb0JXKncO30D1zlDSsJwEdqFYrGPm5xKlgioGDNzGcHp 3NzukYfScMBG+Tsc4tIGARlLnrAnWgFQGY0xkLWT8SflyVwc4NCAOp/dlP/OvlXh0HxD3892FDDK gakiBgEuYOkqHJLT+h0dldSgx1CrDezibyV/g/OGiJpnovIJzflUDtG9b8caIarEvfvngz/pdm3F YEnIWlgrDkfUJleWftUulkbC12DciiOUAQy3WRoWhjJ4ABRp4spTBKsH/WzE78WB+6LKJkk4wWD9 KG0tzgOmmMGaUP9zdaSt+fXBg4AgtUTWwY0EZbFdY0Y475ECIEdzEsxR9IQpYAq9Q1/YcKzYTCaM s2+j9wH3Q1T0OnzHr9QTD70ParuHFtM+m4WpRRDP6YzwkAPgQJbLUn1IyorvEsb916X6hS2cYjIJ 6FvP59D5/tcVDyIlYJek2rIwTUPUT8QT3vILHyjSgsurxMQHlPSHajqDoBSIPAlbDjazCbhs7qBp ykynMq3lH+/mc7mO0J3xwAs1o4F30afXq/Il88LGHIf1OBs3SpJ8iA7mf/iPUTAhEEkrbAUeWi7B D+eU9T0DQavwqFLBkhUceQvg7Kqn0sE1nXryKm1ntl0yyWbH0PqjkrVu2M5IvaqorltwZOQvoHZj olVKHHO8KOMZCmc82QXQzBdE/0WUF6s9jksWWuRuNY/WRg==
X-Report-Abuse-To: spam@antispammaster.host-h.net

--=_0964fc6b5afd6aeec2ef8cae672582fa
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

 

         [1] 

MERRY CHRISTMAS

Thank you all for the support of our largest annual fundraiser. May you,
your family and friends enjoy a blessed Christmas, and a joyous 2023. You
can still get your globe through to the end of December. We will keep the
lights on for you. Get Your Globe - Only R60 each [1] 

         [1] 

As we are reminded every day of the value of special time with friends and
family, we just love this time of year. Memories shared and enjoyed through
the festive season are particularly memorable. With thanks for the support
through 2022, we hope you embrace the times shared and wish you all a
blessed 2023. 

We thank you all 

The Highway Hospice provide care for the terminally ill 002-409NPO

Don't want to receive any more email from us?
Simply unsubscribe [2] from our list. 

 

Links:
------
[1] https://crm./civicrm/mailing/url/?u=237&qid=22813-globe-tree-of-light/
[2] https://crm./civicrm/mailing/url/?u=238&qid=22813-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/tedc15/*|UNSUB|*

--=_0964fc6b5afd6aeec2ef8cae672582fa
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  
</head>
    <body style="background-color: #202020; color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0;" text="#FFFFFF">
        <center><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="background-color: #202020;" id="ko_heroBlock_1">

                <tbody><tr>
                    <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #F5F5F5;">
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="660">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 660px;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                                    <!-- // HERO WITH LEFT CTA -->
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #FAFAFA; border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 2px solid #E0E0E0; max-width: 660px;">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size: 0; padding: 10px;">
                                                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="bottom">
                                                            <a target="_new" href="https://crm./civicrm/mailing/url/?u=235&amp;qid=22813" rel='nofollow'><img alt="Get your Globe" height="200" width="640" style="border: 0; height: auto; max-width: 640px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%;" src="https://crm./civicrm/mosaico/img/?src=https%3A%2F%2Fcrm.%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fcivicrm%2Fpersist%2Fcontribute%2Fimages%2Fuploads%2FTreeOfLightTop_f41063eeb004001a4d86dd1078e7cd43.png&amp;method=cover&amp;params=640%2C200"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640">
                                                <tr>
                                                <td align="left" valign="top" width="340">
                                                <![endif]-->
                                                <div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 340px; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 340px;">
                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 10px 0;">
                                                                <h2 style="color: #202020; font: 24px/28px Rawlinson, Georgia, 'Times', 'Times New Roman', serif; margin: 10px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">Merry Christmas</h2>
                                                                <p style="color: #606060; font: 16px/22px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">Thank you all for the support of our largest annual fundraiser.&nbsp; May you, your family and friends enjoy a blessed Christmas, and a joyous 2023.&nbsp; You can still get your globe through to the end of December.&nbsp; We will keep the lights on for you.</p>
                                                                <a target="_new" href="https://crm./civicrm/mailing/url/?u=235&amp;qid=22813" rel='nofollow' style="background-color: #5A712D; border-top: 10px solid #5A712D; border-right: 20px solid #5A712D; border-bottom: 10px solid #5A712D; border-left: 20px solid #5A712D; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: #E0E0E0 0 2px 0; color: #FFFFFF; display: inline-block; font: 18px/24px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; letter-spacing: .5px; margin: 5px auto 10px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">Get Your Globe - Only R60 each</a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody></table>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="right" valign="top" width="300">
                                                <![endif]-->
                                                <div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 300px; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                                                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 300px;">
                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                                <a target="_new" href="https://crm./civicrm/mailing/url/?u=235&amp;qid=22813" rel='nofollow'><img alt="Get your Globe of Remembrance here" height="200" width="300" style="border: 0; height: auto; max-width: 300px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%;" src="https://crm./civicrm/mosaico/img/?src=https%3A%2F%2Fcrm.%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fcivicrm%2Fpersist%2Fcontribute%2Fimages%2Fuploads%2FTreeOfLightKid_dc908126dfb5985ced08d749b2ea9f8b.png&amp;method=cover&amp;params=300%2C200"></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody></table>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <![endif]-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                    <!-- HERO WITH LEFT CTA // -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody></table>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 1-COLUMN SCAFFOLD // -->
            </tbody></table><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="background-color: #202020;" id="ko_footerBlock_3">

                <tbody><tr>
                    <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #202020;">
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 40px 20px 60px;">
                                    <p style="color: #e0e0e0; font: 14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin: 0 0 2px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;" data-mce-style="color: #e0e0e0; font: 14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin: 0 0 2px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">As we are reminded every day of the value of special time with friends and family, we just love this time of year.&nbsp; Memories shared and enjoyed through the festive season are particularly memorable.&nbsp; With thanks for the support through 2022, we hope you embrace the times shared and wish you all a blessed 2023.&nbsp;</p><p style="color: #e0e0e0; font: 14px/18px Frutiger,
'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin: 0 0 2px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;" data-mce-style="color: #e0e0e0; font: 14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin: 0 0 2px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;"><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p style="color: #e0e0e0; font: 14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin: 0 0 2px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;" data-mce-style="color: #e0e0e0; font: 14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin: 0 0 2px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">We thank you all&nbsp;</p>
                                    <p style="color: #aaaaaa; font: 14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;" data-mce-style="color: #aaaaaa; font: 14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">The Highway Hospice provide care for the terminally ill 002-409NPO<br></p>
                                    <p style="color:#AAAAAA; font:14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0; text-align:center;"><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p style="color:#AAAAAA; font:14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0; text-align:center;"><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p style="color:#AAAAAA; font:14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0; text-align:center;"><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p style="color:#AAAAAA; font:14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin:0 0 10px 0;
padding:0; text-align:center;"><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p style="color:#AAAAAA; font:14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0; text-align:center;"><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p style="color:#AAAAAA; font:14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0; text-align:center;"><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p style="color:#AAAAAA; font:14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0; text-align:center;"><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p style="color:#AAAAAA; font:14px/18px Frutiger, 'Frutiger Linotype', 'Helvetica Neue',
Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0; text-align:center;">Don't want to receive any more email from us?<br>Simply <a href="https://crm./civicrm/mailing/url/?u=236&amp;qid=22813" rel='nofollow' target="_blank" style="color:#E0E0E0;">unsubscribe</a> from our list.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 1-COLUMN SCAFFOLD // -->
            </tbody></table></center>
    
</body></html>
<img src="https://crm./civicrm/mailing/open/?qid=22813" width='1' height='1' alt='' border='0'>
--=_0964fc6b5afd6aeec2ef8cae672582fa--
```

Comment: I've never seen this - but I don't think this can be answered without viewing the full source of your email (you can exclude headers though for privacy).  It's also very difficult to read a screenshot of text.  Could you please edit the question to get the full HTML of the email as text, particularly the top of it?  How to view the full HTML varies by mail client, but this link explains [getting full HTML for Outlook and GMail](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/knowledge-base/how-do-i-view-the-html-code-of-an-email/).  In Thunderbird, select the email, then press Ctrl-U.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech - thanks, have made the edits

Comment: I'll try to find time to look this over - but meanwhile, I see your SPF and DKIM are failing, which means a lot of these are going to end up in spam mailboxes.  Definitely something worth investigating meanwhile :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify which versions of PHP your ISP moved you from and to. Also which version of CiviCRM are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Speculating: the shift from php 7.4 to php 8.1.  This has messed with my mosaico output also. Rolling back to 7.4 fixes the problem so far, but at some point one must move on.  Back to problem now and 7.4 is deprecated now, don't want to roll back this time.

Comment: I can confirm, with one server instance I manage, with several iterations now of trying to upgrade PHP, that Mosaico mail doesn't work with PHP 8, but works just fine with PHP 7.  This is getting harder to support now due to Drupal no longer supporting PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

We've just come across this and found it works on debian

php8.1-common                        8.1.18-1+0~20230517.40+debian11~1.gbpad774c

but not on cpanel

ea-php81.x86_64                             8.1.19-2.3.1.cpanel  @EA4

A workaround was found, switch to smtp in civimail config.